# how to call a daemonized program from a normal program

Tags: c

I wanted to create 2 applications:

1. A daemon program which communicates with all system related commands.
2. A normal program which executes the daemon program created by me.

So is there a way to do this, as far as I am concerned I got the info that we can do it by using `exec*()` and `fork()` but I'm not sure about that. Any examples would be appreciated as I am a newbie.

EDIT1:
-EXAMPLE
I need a Program where the daemon will call the "date" command(not specifically date but including all other system commands) without **super** user privileges (aka root) and in-turn the daemon program should be called by my application created by me.

Comment: I have the normal program write a command for the deamon to `/tmp` file. Then I wake up the sleeping daemon by killing the `sleep` command running under it. The deamon wakes up, reads the `/tmp` file and executes the command there. See: https://github.com/WinEunuuchs2Unix/eyesome

Comment: What do you mean by "communicates with all system related commands?" That seems like you are asking how to use dbus (look it up). Many services on your Ubuntu system communicate via dbus with each other and with the user client.

Comment: i did make an edit in the question do check it out for more information